# MPMoviePlayerController mp4 file streaming

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

I have few links to .mp4 video files like

file1.mp4
file2.mp4
file3.mp4

I need to play them all in player as one file. Actually not necessarily "as one" file, the player must act like it's one file. My best guess is to create custom controls and playback area for `MPMoviePlayerController` and divide the playback by time slices.

For instance

file1.mp4 file2.mp4 file3.mp4

-----------|------------|------------

Is this a good approach? Can this be done anyhow easier?

Also, the server, from which I'll get the videos is not customizable and I can't convert videos to MPEG-2 and stream them via .m3u8 files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those movie resources played from a local source or are they played progressively while downloading?

Comment: They are streamed from server.

Comment: So you can't merge those files on the server side?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. Server is not my responsibility and it is already complete. Also merging them on server side is pretty costly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sticked up to the scenario I described in the question and was able to create the player component.

Comment: @ArminM I've dug out the code, but there's way too many dependencies and I'd have to post a lot of formatted code here. I don't really have the time to post a proper answer, so please contact me via this email: e.reshetov@g-sg.net (just write whatever) and I'll send you the project and explanations as to where and what to look for in it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVQueuePlayer). It supports multi-item playback. Haven't tried that myself (I used AVPlayer for single-item playback). I believe that AVQueuePlayer usage should reduce your overall efforts. ( You will still be responsible for drawing playback controls )

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it and will post my comments.

Comment: Again, thanks. But this is not what I needed. AVQueuePlayer does not support streaming video.

Comment: Strange, because AVPlayer supports streaming from server, if url is formed correctly.